# How to get all substring between a string and replace

Tags: php, html, string

I have the following string in php

```
<?php 

$data = 'The good <b>PEOPLE LIVES LONG</b>. The bad <b>PEOPLE DIES FAST</b>';
   ?>
```

I want to extract the part between   tag and replace it with my own text. here is the function I used to just get the text between the   tag.

```
function GetStringBetween ($string, $start, $finish) {
$string = " ".$string;
$position = strpos($string, $start);
if ($position == 0) return "";
$position += strlen($start);
$length = strpos($string, $finish, $position) - $position;
return substr($string, $position, $length);
}
```

If I called the function with

```
    GetStringBetween ($data, '<b>', '</b>')
```

It works when i.e the data is

```
    $data = 'The good <b>PEOPLE LIVES LONG</b>.';
```

But it doesn't work here when the data contains more multiple pairs of   i.e when

```
     $data = 'The good <b>PEOPLE LIVES LONG</b>. The bad <b>PEOPLE DIES FAST</b>';
```

I need help with function to always replace string between  the  **and**  with my own text no matter how many times it appears.

Comment: You're not looking for [`$data = preg_replace('~<b.*?</b>~s', "my text", $data);`](https://eval.in/577696) do you.

Comment: Thanks bro, it is, although I tweak it a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try preg_match :

```
preg_match('/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/i', $string, $matches);
```

Comment: Cheers Happy coding.